# Why does this extra ">" symbol is coming in my html page?

Tags: html, css

- Extra symbol is coming ">", can u find out where is this extra >
  symbol
- Why this ">" symbol is coming in above ?

**HTML**

```
          <table>
 <tr><td>Hi <%username%>,</td></tr>


<tr><td><b>Greetings from Sunlight IT</b></td></tr>


<tr><td>Earlier you are assigned for a <%keyword%> keyword to get <%OldPosition%> position. Your keyword assigned keyword date was <%oldStartDate%> and Previous target date was <%oldtargetdated%> which you couldn't reach your target position.So once again, I'm assigning <%keyword%> keyword to get <%NewPosition%> position. Newly assigned date is <%NewStartDate%>and target date is <%Newtargetdate%></td></tr>

<tr><td>This time try to achieve the target position i.e <%NewPosition%> for the keyword <%keyword%> with out fail.
</td></tr>

<tr><td>Thanks & Regards</td></tr>
<tr><td>Project Manager</td></tr>

<tr><td>Sunlight IT</td></tr>

<tr><td>My desk   | 91 40 5454</td></tr>

<tr><td>t | 91 40 4545</td></tr>

<tr><td>e  | support@gdgds.com</td></tr>

<tr><td>w | www.sunlifdfasghtit.com</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the css ? we are not magicians

Comment: are `<br/>`tags in your code? if yes remove it.

Comment: i have not used any css and i have removed  <br/> but still getting space

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b30fqc7y/  br's are problem, see by your self... When i set br's display to none - no extra space.

Comment: Please, never ever use tables for layout purposes. That goes against every rule of layout and structure separation from css and html

Comment: @Markai: how/where is he using tables for layout purposes?

Comment: @IkoTikashi he is using the table to layout his text.

Comment: @Markai He is not layouting anything, he is just abusing a table for no purpose at all! But that is not the issue here; let's concentrate on his problems, OK?

Comment: @Markai: that's not layout, he just uses the table to create different rows, nothing wrong with that

Comment: If you examine the html it would seem that this is a template for an html email. In which case tables are the best way to maintain compatibility across readers.

Comment: Actually im preparing a template to send a mail . this a template which i want use to send mail 
 StreamReader r = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/KeywordManageMail.txt"));
            string body = r.ReadToEnd();
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

Comment: Did you just completely change the question? Would've been better to state a new question, your previous one was solved. Anyway, search for `>>` on this page and you'll see why you get that extra `>`

Comment: Looking at your code: `<tr><td>My desk   | 91 40 5454</td></tr>>` there's a double end marker, <br /> or <br/> should not make another marker appear

Comment: yes i removed that <tr/>> but still im facing same problem. that > is not vanishing.@Cheshire

Comment: I don't see an extra `>` when I paste this into jsfiddle. But anyway, the source you posted here, this template, is not real HTML. Does the problem persist if you replace all the `<%identifier%>` thingies with some random word?. And the solitary `&` is not OK either, but that won't cause troubles here.

Comment: yes in jsfiddle and w3schools editors there is no issue. in my visual studio it was coming like that . i deleted that page and created another html page and copy pasted that code then it worked properly, not showed any extra symbol . Thanks for ur Help @MrLister

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all of the `<br/>` in your table, they're not allowed there.

Comment: i have removed all <br/> tags , still that space is not removing

Comment: @krishnamohan Are you sure? See the fiddles in my answer; this definitely solves the case.

Comment: @krishnamohan: sure? Because removing them solves the problem, since you're not using styles/css. Make sure to edit the correct page.

Comment: @IkoTikashi you are right ,after removing 
</br > space is removed.

Comment: Nice. Please mark @MrLister s answer as correct then.

Answer (score 5):

You have `<br/>` elements in your table, outside of any table cells. That is forbidden by the HTML spec; all content inside a table should be in a table cell.

See the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xnox83g7) made from your source, and [the same](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/xnox83g7/1/) with the `<br/>`s removed.

Edit: the *reason* why the `<br>` causes extra space is that the browser doesn't know what to do with them, so it puts them all on top, before the contents of the first `<tr>` instead of in between the `<tr>`s where you expected them.
And all browsers handle this in the same way, unlike most other errors I could mention. So it's best not to have errors at all.